# PHP Group Array Data - Make, Model, SKU

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

I am using a mysql query to return an array of products that are suitable for certain cars in php which looks like this;

```
array { 

[0]=> array(3) { 
    ["sku"]=> string(16) "123a " 
    ["make"]=> string(20) "Ford" 
    ["model"]=> string(25) "Escort" 
    } 

[1]=> array(3) { 
    ["sku"]=> string(16) "123b" 
    ["make"]=> string(20) "Ford" 
    ["model"]=> string(25) "Escort" 
    } 

[2]=> array(3) { 
    ["sku"]=> string(16) "123c" 
    ["make"]=> string(20) "Ford" 
    ["model"]=> string(25) "Focus" 
    } 

[3]=> array(3) { 
    ["sku"]=> string(16) "123d" 
    ["make"]=> string(20) "Alfa Romeo" 
    ["model"]=> string(25) "159" 
    } 

[4]=> array(3) { 
    ["sku"]=> string(16) "123e" 
    ["make"]=> string(20) "Alfa Romeo" 
    ["model"]=> string(25) "159" 
    } 

}
```

I am trying to workout how to use a foreach loop to go through the data and end up with a newly grouped/nested array that would be along the lines of;

```
[Ford]=>
{["model"]=>"Escort" ["skus"]=>("123a", "123b)}
{["model"]=>"Focus" ["skus"]=>("123c")}

["Alfa Romeo]=>
{["model"]=>"159" ["skus"]=>("123d", "123e")}
```

So I'd like to group all records by 'make', sub group by make & model and then put all the skus for that make model combination together.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: If you'd pasted the results of echo var_export($data, 1); it'd be easier for others to copy/paste and work directly on ... just saying.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This loop gives expected result:

```
$summary = array();

foreach ($data as $row)
{
    if (!isset($summary[$row['make']]))
    {
        $summary[$row['make']][] = array(
            'model' => $row['model'],
            'skus'  => array($row['sku'])
        );
    }
    else
    {
        $modelExist = false;

        foreach ($summary[$row['make']] as $i => $make)
        {
            if ($make['model'] == $row['model'])
            {
                $summary[$row['make']][$i]['skus'][] = $row['sku'];
                $modelExist = true;
                break;
            }
        }

        if (!$modelExist)
        {
            $summary[$row['make']][] = array(
                'model' => $row['model'],
                'skus'  => array($row['sku'])
            );
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could do something like this (the output wouldn't be exactly what you asked for, but would be easier to work with):

```
$output = array();
foreach ($cars as $car) {
    $output[$car['make']][$car['model']][] = $car['sku'];
}
```

Which would give you the following output:

```
[Ford] => Array
    [Escort] => Array
        [0] => 123a
        [1] => 123b
    [Focus] => Array
        [0] => 123c
[Alfa Romeo] => Array
    [159] => Array
        [0] => 123d
        [1] => 123e
```

#### [Demo](http://codepad.viper-7.com/ySPjyl)

Comment: Superstar!  Thank you so much, that's actually even better than I was trying to get originally.